# FFMpeg multiple actions with the same filter_complex

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm working with 2 videos and I want to make 3 different operations at same 
execution with FFmpeg. Each command works separate but it'll much more efficient to make them all run at the same execution.

So for example I have:

**Video 1**

**Video 2**

First I want to cut both videos from starting point to end point:

```
cmd = -i video1Path -ss 00:00:30.0 -c copy -t 00:00:10.0 video1Output
cmd = -i video2Path -ss 00:00:30.0 -c copy -t 00:00:10.0 video2Output
```

Than resizing **Video 1**:

```
cmd = "-i " + video1Output+ " -vf scale=240:360" + resizedVideo1;
```

Now overlaying the **resizedVideo1** on top of **Video 2**:

```
cmd = "-i " + video2Output + " -i " + resizedVideo1 + " -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]" + overlayCmd + " " + finalVideoPath;
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve all this actions at the same FFMpeg executions using 1 filter_complex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combined command will be

```
ffmpeg -ss 30 -t 10 -i video2 -ss 30 -t 10 -i video1
  -filter_complex
        "[1]scale=240:360[v1];[0][v1]overlay"
  output.mp4
```

Comment: Works perfect! is it needed to add the -coded copy attr to avoid re-encoding?

Comment: If you are using filters, you can't copy. You can do `-c:a copy` since you aren't filtering audio.

Comment: Do i have to add to each video input -c:a copy, or just the one im using it's audio?

Comment: Just once, and after the filters.